# Why Grease Pencil will only let me draw a circle around a red dot? - 2.8

Tags: grease-pencil

Out of the blue this red dot appeared on my canvas. And when I try to draw, the only strokes I can do are those around the red dot, making a circle around it. I can draw near or far from the dot making a big or large circle. Nothing else!
If I use a different tool, like the Fill, or the Eraser, the red dot goes away.

What could I have inadvertently activated?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your issue. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Answer (score 4):

Apparently I switched on guides by accident...
[image]